# Show that $ker(f) = n/k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

We suppose that we have integers, $n$ and $k$, such that there exists a ring homomorphism defined as : $$f : \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$$ where  $\overline{x} \rightarrow [x]$.

Show that,

(i) k divides n.

(ii) the number of elements in $ker(f)$ is equal to $n/k$.

(iii) $f$ is surjective.

I have been able to show (i), but I am not sure for (ii) and (iii).

For (ii), I have started by using the definition of $ker(f)$. We have $ker(f) = \{\overline{x}, f(\overline{x}) = [0]\} = \{\overline{x}, [x] = [0] = [k]\} = \{\overline{x}, k/x\} = \{\overline{x}, \text{such that x is a multiple of k}\}$. From that point, I don't see how I can conclude that $ker(f) = n/k$, would it be useful to use (i) ?

Also for (iii), we know that $f$ is a ring homomorphism and we know that the homomorphism is entirely determined by it generators. From that the only two generators are $\overline{1}$ and $[1]$ so then we can conclude that $f(\overline{x})=[x]$.

If someone have any ideas for (ii) and (iii), I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Let me denote by $[x]_n$ the residue class of $x$ modulo $n$. Then you have
$$
f([x]_n)=[x]_k
$$
and, in particular,
$$
f([0]_n)=f([n]_n)=[n]_k=[0]_k
$$
Therefore $n\equiv0\pmod{k}$, that is, $k\mid n$.

What's the kernel of $f$? You have $[x]_n\in\ker f$ if and only if $[x]_k=[0]_k$, that is, if and only if $k\mid x$. Hence $\ker f=k\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, which has precisely $n/k$ elements.

Why? The homomorphism $f$ is clearly surjective, because $[x]_k=f([x]_n)$, and the homomorphism theorem tells you that
$$
(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})/\ker f\cong\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}
$$
Therefore
$$
n/\lvert\ker f\rvert=k
$$
by Lagrange's theorem.

---

You now might be interested in showing that if $k\mid n$, then there *does* exist a unique ring homomorphism (preserving the unit elements) $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$. Which is precisely $[x]_n\mapsto[x]_k$.

Comment: Thanks ! But to show that $f$ is surjective can we use the generators of this homomorphism ? Yes that's also another subquestion,. Is it possible to use the fact that $g$ is also a ring homomorphism $g : \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}$, then we know that $g([1]_n) = [1]_k \implies  g([1]_n) = f([1]_n) \implies f = g$ ?

Comment: @ola Why bother? Surjectivity is completely obvious even if the homomorphism doesn't map the unit into the unit. Yes, with $1\mapsto1$, you prove uniqueness.